# Error with lxml syntax to parse table elements while validating column contents

Tags: python, html, lxml

I have the following code to parse html table. How do I check for a specified text in `<td>` element? This doesn't work : `val=doc.xpath('//tr/td[child::*[text()="Street :"]/span/text()')`. I am trying to extract the `<span>` text only when the `<td>` text matches 'Street :'. Any feedback is much appreciated!

```
import lxml.html as lh

html='''<tr>
<td>
Street : <span> High St. </span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
City : <span> Hightstown </span>
</td>
</tr>'''

doc=lh.fromstring(html)

#val=doc.xpath('//tr/td[child::*[text()="Street :"]/span/text()')
#street=doc.xpath('//tr/td/text()')
val=doc.xpath('//tr/td/span/text()')

#print street
print val
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> doc.xpath('//tr/td[contains(text(),"Street :")]/span/text()')
[' High St. ']
```

Comment: Awesome! Can you please point me to other sources where all the options in xpath are listed? lxml.de is not of much help.

Comment: You can find it in [XPath specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/). Unfortunately I can't give your better source.